# How to process crystal based source of energy into liquid form?

Tags: energy, power-sources

I start to write sci-fi story and there's a chapter where a mining plant will work with this source of energy called Extrenum. This energy was taken out from crystal rocks material but I wonder if it can be transformed into liquid energy so it can be put in containers like large tubes and to install them in the mining chamber gears.

What's the common known process steps to transform crystal based source energy to liquid form? Melting it in high temperature will be common I am sure, but is it possible to add more process steps?

How many Extrenum tubes needed to run the a mining gear will also relate to how much crystal rock to melt down.

I came across [a reference of fictional Power Sources](https://www.saveonenergy.com/iconic-fictional-power-sources/) and I am also thinking that this Extrenum should have measurement unit to describe the energy output.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, She N3rd! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

Comment: Your question is currently a bit hard to answer objectively because we don’t know enough about the crystals in your world. As we don’t have any of your “crystal-based energy sources” in real life, you’ll have to give us some more details about them so we can give you a best possible answer.

Comment: for instance if energy is extracted by burning them like coal, then there really is on way to liquify it, it combusts before it melts.

Comment: "Liquid Energy" makes no sense.  Energy is not matter, so it doesn't have a state.  It cannot be liquid, solid, gas, plasma, or any other state of matter.  Please clarify what you mean by this.

Comment: This question isn't unclear, the OP is looking for ways to convert a solid crystal to a liquid.  Please, ladies and gentlemen, don't get lost in the backstory.  It doesn't matter *why* the OP wants to do this unless you think there's a better way to get from crystal to liquid than the backstory allows, which isn't the case here.  I'm voting to keep this Q open.

Comment: Matter (solid or liquid) is not energy.  You can extract energy from matter in a number of ways:  storage (take a rock to the top of a tall building), chemical (burning), nuclear (radiation), conversion (add anti-matter and BOOM), and magic (because: crystal).  First, how does the crystal store or generate energy?  How do you get that energy out.  How does melting the crystal affect the energy storage?  Maybe you grind it up and mix with water of something?

Answer (score 2):

Well, what can you do with a crystal?

1:  You can dissolve it in water or some other liquid.  That would get you a liquid.  If you want physically plausible this would work.  The dissolving of crystals is often exothermic.  If you hold table salt in your hand and add a little water you might feel it get warm.  Try this with calcium chloride or sodium tetra borate and it gets plenty warm.  Your crystal could dissolve slowly and heat the solvent to boiling as it does, producing useful energy.

2:  You could distill lighter fractions off of it, like one would do with a petrochemical.  That would be with heat or vacuum or both.  The lighter fractions could be liquid.

3:  You can melt it.

4:  Yes, yes.  But how about something less conventional?

I propose that you use **homeopathic potentization**.

Homeopathic medicines are produced starting with a template substance - usually an herb or compound of some sort but you could definitely use a crystal.  Through a series of dilutions and successions the original substance lends its energy to the water that comprises the medicine, rearranging its structure to confer medicinal powers.

https://www.homeopathycenter.org/homeopathy-today/thought-behind-action-potency-what-it-and-what-it-means

> There is no other process that is fully analogous to potentization,
>   but it may be helpful to compare it with distillation. Distilling a
>   liquid removes certain of its components and retains others, creating
>   a product which is in some ways similar and in some ways different
>   from its source. The potentization process is like distillation in
>   that certain properties of the original substance are gradually
>   winnowed away while others are retained; in potentization, though, the
>   aspects of the substance which remain are changed and even intensified
>   by the process. Specifically, the material structure of the substance
>   fades away while its energetic aspect is magnified.

You start with a crystal and wind up with a potentized solution.  I have never read a science fiction which incorporated homeopathic principles, and maybe yours will be the first!

Comment: Not a fan of the homeopathic solution. While information on homeopathy sites states *"certain properties [...] are gradually winnowed away while others are retained"* the original substance is so diluted in the end your results is completely void of it. It can not be measured and you can not scientifically distinguish two different substances diluted using the same method. They are chemically identical. [Hence the protest in belgium where people took potentized snake venom and other poisons - and none died.](https://www.homeowatch.org/articles/jaroff.html)

Comment: @ArtificialSoul - the fun thing about homeopathy in a scifi context is there is a century's worth of of homeopathic "science" to draw upon in explaining the world and actions therein.  You don't have to invent it!   People suspend disbelief for FTL travel and transporter beams all the time.  Homeopathy should get some leniency too, especially if used creatively within the story.    Extra fun: to a certain type of scientific mind, the mere premise of homeopathy provokes outrage!  

Comment: Suspending disbelief in a fictional world is fine. Personally, I think it is important to note, what is and what is not science. Most people don't do a lot of research. And if someone like you, who often answers questions based in science, just states something like potentization would work without clarifying its lack of basis in the real world, it just rubs me the wrong way. Scientific illiteracy is already a huge problem, please don't enhance it.

Comment: @ArtificialSoul - point taken; sometimes I think about younger readers of the stack and sometimes I forget.

Answer (score 1):

Crystals are structures that are characterized by the ordered arrangement of the atoms.

By definition, [Ice Crystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_crystals) are crystals. When the temperature is above 0 degree, ice melts and becomes water that is a liquid. Note that not all crystals react this way and have those properties, but since the Extrenum doesn't exist for real, you can give it the properties that you want. It can be obtained from a really cold place and becomes a liquid at the temperature you want like ice, lower than the ambient temperature.

Since you extracted it from rock, you also need to purify it, by eliminating the dust and other elements inside. There are many [techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_purification_methods_in_chemistry) to purify a liquid. The most frequent and easy (those I used the most in college) are filtration, distillation, centrifugation and evaporation. When you have your pure liquid Extrenum, you can put it in tubes.

When the process is complete, you can make your Extrenum become unstable at high temperature to produce energy or make it reacts with a particular molecule.

For the measurement unit, those used for energy are generally Joules. One gallon of gasoline is approximately 130000000 J. To compare if your system is good or not, you need to tell how many of this energy you can liberate per second using Joules per seconds or Watt (1 W = 1 J/sec).